# Manual link react-native-fs in react native

Tags: react-redux, react-native, react-native-fs

I'm mac user and "react-native link react-native-fs" doesn’t work for me. How to manually link this?
its just matter for me to work in android.

and please check that im do the right thing till here
first thing i do is

```
npm install react-native-fs --save
```

then i do this in android/setting.gradle

```
include ':react-native-fs'
project(':react-native-fs').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../node_modules/react- 
native-fs/android')
```

and after that in android/app/build.gradle i add this

```
dependencies {
...
implementation project(':react-native-fs')
}
```

and in this step in tutorial said do this

```
import com.rnfs.RNFSPackage; // <------- add package

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
// ...
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
    new MainReactPackage(), // <---- add comma
    new RNFSPackage() // <---------- add package
  );
}
```

but my code is little bit diffrent and thats it

```
@Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      //return packages;
      return packages(
    new MainReactPackage(), // <---- add comma
    new RNFSPackage() // <---------- add package
  );
    }
```

and at this step tutorial said to do 'react-native link react-native-fs'
but it doesn't work for me
so i think the solution is to link manually but i dont know how to do that

Comment: Hello, Did you solve the issue, I am facing the save problem?

Answer (score 2):

Process to link should be like this

```
npm install react-native-fs --save
```

once installed you have to link the same dependency to the gradle file

```
npm link react-native-fs
```

open your settings.gradle file and the linking should be there.
If not then only manually add

```
include ':react-native-fs'
project(':react-native-fs').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fs/android')
```

go to your build.gradle file of Module app and add the missing dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-fs')
    // your other implementations 

}
```

Comment: Dude it doesnt work for me its not even running anymore and i had to delete the react-native-fs to run again and also you dont expalin about what i should do in MainApllication.java